# Use extra columns in INSERT values list in ON CONFLICT UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have an UPSERT query where I want to insert value `y` value in column `b`, but if it already exists I want to update it with value `z`.

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b)
select P.x,P.y
from (VALUES 
    ('123', 4, 5),
    ('345', 2, 2)  
) K(x,y,z)
ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE
SET b = K.z;
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S: A simple value list (without select) did not work because we cannot have more columns in values list than we are inserting.

Comment: `('345', 2, 2)` this bug me...

Comment: Should it be something else?

Comment: if insert with `2` got duplicate then update it to `2` ? which origin data already is `2` because there is a conflict ? what sorcery is this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was not clear. My conflict is dependent on column `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `SET` part, you can only reference columns of the target table and the corresponding "values" through the `excluded` record. Neither of them has a column named `z`

The only way I can think of, is to put the values into a CTE and access the column `z` through a sub-query:

```
with data (x,y,z) as (
  VALUES 
      (123, 4, 6),
      (345, 2, 3)  
)
INSERT INTO test (a,b)
select d1.x, d1.y
from data d1
ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE
  SET b = (select d2.z from data d2 where d2.x = excluded.a);
```

The above assumes that `a` is the primary (or unique) key of the table.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff9c52c7d3e20b2462705a4dc77d6ba9)

Comment: I knew you would come to my rescue. I did try with CTE but didn't think of selecting it from a different from clause in UPDATE. Thank you!
What do you think of the performance? My values list can have up to 20K rows. Without CTE I get around 300ms.